# c# MySql select users by distance

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, iis

I am using this code to select users from table in MySql,after i select i calculate the distance between the users and add only the users that are in 10KM from a gps location.

```
        string commandLine = "SELECT * FROM Users;";

        using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandLine, connect))
        {
            connect.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader msdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

                while (msdr.Read())
                {
                    double lon2 = msdr.GetDouble(19);
                    double lat2 = msdr.GetDouble(20);

                    double k = this.GetDistance(lat, lon, lat2, lon2);
                    //k is the distance
                    if (k <= 10)
                    {
                        //Add item to array
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And i want to know if there is a possible to do this calculate with the Sql command instead in the code, because every time i get all the users from a table.

Edit

This is the GetDistance method:

```
private double GetDistance(double lat,double lon,double lat2,double lon2)
    {
        double ee = (3.1415926538 * lat / 180);
        double f = (3.1415926538 * lon / 180);
        double g = (3.1415926538 * lat2 / 180);
        double h = (3.1415926538 * lon2 / 180);
        double r = (Math.Cos(ee) * Math.Cos(g) * Math.Cos(f) * Math.Cos(h) + Math.Cos(ee) * Math.Sin(f) * Math.Cos(g) * Math.Sin(h) + Math.Sin(ee) * Math.Sin(g));
        double j = (Math.Acos(r));
        double k = (6371 * j);

        return k;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the GetDistance method.

Comment: Basically, assuming the logic that's in GetDistance will be correct, you want to replicate that in T-SQL.  Ultimately though, it would probably be best to do these calculations on the SQL Server instead of the web server for performance reasons.  So, if you could show the GetDistance logic, we could help translate that into T-SQL logic and correct any problems in the code for you that's not working correctly.

Comment: Even without moving the code into SQL, you can optimise it so you don't have to read all the records. A degree of latitude is a fixed distance anywhere on the globe. You can filter to just those rows within the band of latitude that could possibly be within 10 km of your target. The same is not true of longitude. But it would still reduce the number of rows you have to look at by a substantial amount. If you do move it to SQL, this optimization is still a good thing to do.

Comment: @Carmine I add the GetDistance method logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically injected the formula right into the SQL statement. Try something like this:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM Users HAVING distance <= 10 ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: Actually let me make a quick correction to this to get you users that are within 10K only

Comment: I was in the process of writing a full statement. I accidentally hit Submit prematurely.

Comment: Statement complete. Try something like this. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's almost always a way to do similar things in T-SQL.  T-SQL supports a variety of Math operations, so you can create variables, assign variables, and use them in your T-SQL logic when selecting users.

Please reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177516.aspx for further information.